# PHP mail issues - will not send email

Tags: php, email

I am currently working on a simple form and i want the info to be collected by a php script and then sent to me as a mail, but i am not receiving the specific email.

Could anybody give any pointers or highlight the problem? thank you

Here is the code for my form:

```
<form name="bookingForm" method="post" action="send_dates.php">
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">

<tr>
    <td>Booking From</td>
        <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="fromDate" id="fromDate" size="20"></td>

    <td>To</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="toDate" id="toDate" size="20"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="20px">Telephone</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="telephone" type="text" id="customer_telephone" size="30"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="20px">Email</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="30"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="ResetForm" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And here is my php script:

```
<?php 

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $fromDate = $_POST['fromDate'];
 $toDate = $_POST['toDate');
 $email = $_POST['customer_email'];
 $telephone = $_POST['customer_telephone'];

// Mail of reciever
$to = "blablabla@blabla.com";

// Contact subject
$subject ="Reservation Enquiry from $name";

// Details
$message="From: $name
Email: $email
Telephone: $customer_telephone
--------------------------------------------------------------
Reservation date from: $fromDate to: $toDate ";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_mail";

// From

$res=mail($to,$subject,$message);
    if($res)
{
    header('Location:index.php');
}

    ?>
```

Comment: i just noticed this now but apparently there is a parse error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/content/51/8418351/html/bofu/send_dates.php on line 20
it is this line: 
$subject ="Reservation Enquiry from $name";

Comment: Did you check your spam mail?

Comment: do you have the correct SMTP server address in PHP.INI?

Comment: i dont know if i have the correct smtp server address...

Comment: Also your attempts are from localhost or from a production system? If you are working from localhost this [article](http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html) might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semicolon missing

```
$to = "blablabla@blabla.com";
```

UPDATE:

Remove  `if(!empty($data))` loop

Check for `$res = mail(...);`

Then put

```
if($res)
         {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                     window.location = "index.php";
                  </script>';
         }
         else
         {
             echo 'something wrong';
         }
```

Comment: how embarrassing. i just corrected this and now it echoes "something is wrong" meaning that the data is not being collected from the form

Comment: Didn't notice that. Where is $data defined?

Comment: thanks, instead of echoing mail sent how can i make the page refresh itself?

Comment: `header('Location:index.php');`

Comment: i get an error and warning saying that i cannot modify the header information because it is already sent... any idea?

Comment: Edited answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Possible cause is a wrong SMTP server address.

Stop the webserver, correct the SMTP server address in PHP.INI, restart the webserver.

You can check the current configuration by executing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and to search for SMTP.

Comment: in what should i change the smtp server address? currently it is relay-hosting.secureserver.net ? thank you

Comment: If your webserver is running local, you need to set the SMTP address. If you're using an online hosting, then this is already set to the correct server for you.